# How to append a cell to a tableview using iOS 9?

Tags: swift, list, uitableview, append

I am using Xcode 7.3 with iOS 9 and Swift. I would like a user to be able to enter an integer into a textfield, tap a button, and then have the integer display in a tableview on the same screen. I would like the user to be able to create a list of integers doing this.

I have my textfield, button, and tableview created. What's the easiest way to code this function?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the you know how to use the standard table view, so that I don't have to post irrelevant code?

Try this.....

Use beginUpdates and endUpdates for insert new cell when button clicked..

First of all append data in your tableview array, let's say the array containing the content for your table view is named `Yourarray`

```
Yourarray.push(0815)  // some integer, which you will grap from the input
```

Then upate your table and insert new row

```
// Update Table Data
tblname.beginUpdates()
tblname.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
    NSIndexPath(forRow: Yourarray.count-1, inSection: 0)
    ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tblname.endUpdates()
```

You can see the line of code with `Yourarray.count-1`. There you can write any integer in which line you want to append the new cell.
If you are using a tableview you should be using an array to populate it with the tableview, I hope you are doing that.

**Edit**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    ...

}
```

firstly you adopt your class from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` .

Then you add these functions inside your class:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0 // how many tableview cells you want to display
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell // "cell" is the identifier in this case, change that in your storyboard

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Your value for the tableview"

        return cell
}
```

[image]

Inside the viewDidLoad you have to add this in order to hook it up:

```
self.zipTable.delegate = self
self.zipTable.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this. Right now the only thing I have coded was to create the connections from the View Controller to the ViewController.swift file. I didn't know where to start.

Comment: Do you know how to make th tableView? I will help you anywhere if you need some help

Comment: Yes do you have a tableViewController or a ViewController with a tableView inside?

Comment: I have a ViewController with a tableView inside. Here is my tableView:

@IBOutlet weak var zipTable: UITableView!

Comment: Got it? follow some tutorials but ask that in a new question. You wanted to know how to append cells or? Or is your question how to make a tableView?